# JSpeex Decoding not working

Tags: java, audio, jspeex

I'm using the JSpeex library for audio encoding.
The encoding seems to work fine. But decoding doesn't.(i.e. I get all zeros as decoded data.)

```
// encoding ///

SpeexEncoder enc = new SpeexEncoder();


// if i use channel as 1 instead of 2 even encoding doesn't work

enc.init(mode, quality, 44100, 2);

enc.processData(b, 0, b.length); // b is byte array i'm trying to encode & then decode

enc.getProcessedData(temp, 0); // save encoded data to temp // temp is byte array

////Decoding /////////

SpeexDecoder dec = new SpeexDecoder();

dec.init(mode,44100,2,true);

dec.processData(temp, 0, temp.length);

dec.getProcessedData(decoded, 0); //decoded is the output byte array which comes only zeros
```

If anyone has any info on this please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is a bit old, but ran into a similar problem with Speex.js (a javascript port).

Not sure if the issue is the same for you, but I found that there was an implicit conversion from `Float32Array` to `Int16Array` that didn't actually convert the data. This meant that all of the `(-1.0,1.0)` float data was essentially integer zeros, and was converted as such.

Just needed to do the conversion to `Int16Array` before passing in the data (so it wouldn't need to do any data conversion within the library) and the output sprang to life :)

Hope that helps. cheers!